# For loop not returning index properly

Tags: c#, indexing

I have a for loop that I use to get the list item for displaying in my line graph. It's very simple but I get an index is out of range error. The way I understand what happens in the for loop is as long as the i is less then the indexCount() it keeps counting. Why is mine going past my index method? I have researched and used breakpoint found nothing and i = my collection size.

```
List<ChartData> points = ChartData.getData();
    for (int i = 0; i < chartData.indexCount(); i++)
    {
        series0.AddItem(points[i].Produced);
        series1.AddItem(points[i].Labeled);
        RadChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.Items.Add(new ChartAxisItem(points[i].CasesLabeled.ToString()));
    }
```

I made a custom index so that I would be able to get most of the rows form the database for display. hence the `chartData.indexCount()` method there. Here is my indexCount method maybe something went wrong here?

```
public int indexCount()
{

    StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
    sqlString.Append("SELECT Count(Number) FROM SomeDB.dbo.Order");

    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    SqlConnection dbConn = DBHelper.getConnection();

    try
    {
        reader = DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), null);
        if (reader != null)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                number = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        dbConn.Close();
        dbConn.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Did you watch its with breakpoint?

Comment: `points.Count` and `chartData.indexCount()` may be different.if second one is bigger then obviously you will get `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: It would be safer to loop to `points.Count` instead of `chartData.indexCount()`.

Comment: @ElvinArzumanoğlu yes it went to 10 which is size of collection

Comment: what does ChartData.getData() this return? may be the value that it returns is less than the count

Comment: Ok. Please, add your indexCount() method value to another variable,, then try the code. Perhaps, it can help you. example: int count=chartData.indexCount();   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++);

Comment: Only one comment! Try to not dispone and close the connection in the TRY, because if something goes wrong, the connection will not close. Add a FINALLY and close and dispose the connection there ;)

Comment: @OscarBralo, `using` statements would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos, you are aware that the `chartData.indexCount` will be executed for EVERY iteration of the `for` loop, right?

Comment: @PauloMorgado yeah! You are right ;) using will be better! Nice one Paulo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend to use ExecutrScalar instead of ExecuteReader.

Second, you have the list of point - and that list know how much items it has (the Count property).... At least use `Math.Min` to make sure you're not overflowing your list.

And just as a good advice - don't close the reader object (or any object which implement IDisposable). Instead, declare the object in using statement:

```
using (reader = DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), null))  
{
    // code which using reader 
}
```

And lastly - don't call indexCount on every iteration... Just save its result to a variable...